# I am learning on how to implement Dependency Injection [DI] in C#. Is this the valid DI program as an example?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

**1. Main Method**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ILogger _log = new Logger();
            IDataAccess _da = new DataAccess();

            BusinessLogic bs = new BusinessLogic(_log,_da);
            bs.ProcessData();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**2. BusinessLogic Class implements IBusinessLogic interface**

```
class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
    {
        ILogger _log;
        IDataAccess _dataAccess;

        public BusinessLogic(ILogger log, IDataAccess dataAccess)
        {
            _log = log;
            _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        }

        public void ProcessData()
        {
            _log.Log("Start");
            Console.WriteLine("process");
            _dataAccess.LoadData();
            _dataAccess.SaveData("processInfo");
            _log.Log("Finish");
        }
    }
```

**3. Logger Class implements ILogger interface**

```
class Logger : ILogger
    {
       public void Log(string p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
```

**4. DataAccess Class implements IDataAccess interface**

```
class DataAccess : IDataAccess
    {
        public void LoadData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loaddata");
        }      

        public void SaveData(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving Data");
        }
    }
```

**4. Interfaces**

```
interface IBusinessLogic
    {
        void ProcessData();
    } 

interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(string p);
    }  

interface IDataAccess
    {
        void LoadData();
        void SaveData(string name);
    }
```

With respect to the above code i have `3 interfaces` for `BusinessLogic`, `Logger` and `DataAccess` for all `3 classes respectively`.....

If this is the `correct implementation for Dependency Injection` then let me know the `improvements or suggestions` for the code if any.....

OR incase it is `NOT correct`, suggest me the modifications to achieve the same.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Yes, it is valid DI, but as things get more complex it is common to use an Inversion of Control container to handle lifetimes and nested dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder, any `improvements/suggestions` within this code?

Comment: Well, all it does it write to the console so there is not much to critique, and code review is off topic on SO but you [can ask here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Crowcoder Out if these `classes` which is `Client class` , `Service class` and `Injector class`? If you could help me with this...

Comment: Sounds like homework. What do you think the answer is?

Comment: @Farhad-Taran Can you please directly edit the improvement said.

Comment: @Crowcoder `Client class - Program`, `Service class - Logger and DataAccess`, `Injector class - BusinessLogic class`?

Comment: I wouldn't go with that... A client is something that consumes a service.

Comment: @Crowcoder `Client class - BusinessLogic class`, `Service class - Logger and DataAccess`, `Injector class - Program class`, this?